# Execute custom js code for my custom payment plugin on woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am creating a fresh custom payment plugin for my woo commerce website. I In that I need to add some custom validation for credit card and some other input fields. I need to add all these validations in a separate js file and wanted to trigger the checkout functionality only after javascript validation is passed successfully.

I'm able to load js using `wp_enqueue_scripts` function but my js code is not executing after checkout button click.
What I want is on checkout click first need to execute my code and based on my validation check need to proceed with checkout functionality.

Comment: Would you please show you code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WooCommerce binds an event on order form and uses AJAX to submit the form (you can see the code in checkout.js).

Here is my solution:

**1.Replace the original submit button with your own button**

in functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', function(){
    return '<button class="new_submit button">Place Order</button>';
});
```

When click the new button, it will not submit the order form directly.

**2.Bind the event on the new button**

```
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.new_submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();       
      if (do_the_validation()){
        jQuery( 'form.checkout' ).submit();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
 })
```

Also, I would recommend you do the server-side validation

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_validation');
function my_validation() { 
    //If it's invalid, add an error.
    if (!do_validation()) {
       wc_add_notice( __( 'Something goes wrong!' ), 'error' );
    }

}
```